# Selenium Python: how to get a list of all strings in a tag

Tags: python, html, string, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get text `("Get this text")` inside the following html using this Xpath: `"//span[@id='myanswer']/text()[7]"`. It finds the text on the website when I put it in the `cntrl+F` field in the inspect html part, but when I try to print the output in my python code it returns nothing. Also doing something like

`driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[@id='myanswer']").text`,

also returns nothing. So I'm thinking maybe appending all those strings into a list and printing the last element of that list? Is there any way of printing out this last string?

```html
<span id="myanswer">
    <br>
    <br> 
    " [&nbsp;"
    <b>tU</b>
    " method Response ]"
    <br>
    "&nbsp;"
    <span class="text-success"><i class="fa  fa-angle-double-right"></i></span>  
    <strong></strong> 
    "&nbsp;" 
    <span class="text-secondary"><i>string</i></span> 
    <b>:</b> 
    "
    &nbsp;Get this text"
    <br>
    <br>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I'm thinking maybe appending all those strings into a list and
> printing the last element of that list

- This is one of the good ways to deal with this text node.

If

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//span[@id='myanswer']").text
```

did not return anything then there could multiple reason:

1.

```
//span[@id='myanswer'] is not unique in HTMLDOM.
```

**Steps to check for uniqueness:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

2. Maybe you are missing a delay, Please put a sleep or use Explicitwait like below:

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='myanswer']"))).get_attribute('innerText')
   ```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: #2 worked for me, I think it was the ".get_attribute('innerText')" part I was missing. Thank you!